# Postgres Refresh Materialized View Locks

Tags: postgresql, materialized-view

I have a materialized view in Postgres, and want to know what locks (if any) are taken out when refreshing that view.

```
CREATE TABLE people ( name VARCHAR(30) );
INSERT INTO people VALUES ('Alice'), ('Bob'), ('Cher');
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW test AS SELECT * FROM people;
REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW test;
```

Specifically, I'm trying to understand whether the `REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW` command takes out an `ACCESS EXCLUSIVE` lock.

I tried an explain with no success:

```
#> EXPLAIN REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW test;

                QUERY PLAN                 
-------------------------------------------
Utility statements have no plan structure
```

Comment: Run the `refresh` statement and check `pg_locks`: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Lock_Monitoring. Or just read the manual: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-refreshmaterializedview.html "*could block other connections which are trying to read from the materialized view*"

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW CONCURRENTLY` takes an `EXCLUSIVE` lock, so `SELECT`s may still run. Per [the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/explicit-locking.html).

There seems to be an oversight with `REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW` (without `CONCURRENTLY`) as it's not listed there. A search of the source code shows that `ExecRefreshMatView` take an `ACCESS EXCLUSIVE` lock, as you might expect, so no other queries may run on the view.

I've submitted a docs patch to list it.

Comment: Side note - the  `CONCURRENTLY` feature is not available until Postgres 9.4.