# What happens if two process try to REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW CONCURRENTLY at the same time?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, materialized-view

According to the docs:

> CONCURRENTLY 
>   Refresh the materialized view without locking out
>   concurrent selects on the materialized view. (...)
>
> ... OTHER CONTENTS ...
>
> Even with this option **only one REFRESH at a time may run against any**
>   **one materialized view**.

I **had** a function that checked the last refresh time for a MATERIALIZED VIEW and, if more than 60 seconds had passed, it would to refresh it.

However, what would happen if I try to refresh a materialized view from two separate processes at the same time? would they queue or would they raise an error?

Is there a way to detect when a MATERIALIZED VIEW is being refreshed and therefore avoid touching it?

Currently, I have resorted to populate a table record before refreshing (setting `refreshing` to `true`) and then setting it to `false` when the process has finished.

```
EXECUTE 'INSERT INTO refresh_status (last_update, refreshing) 
         VALUES (clock_timestamp(), true) RETURNING id') INTO refresh_id;
EXECUTE 'REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW CONCURRENTLY my_mat_view';
EXECUTE 'UPDATE refresh_status SET refreshing=false WHERE id=$1' USING refresh_id;
```

Then, whenever I call this procedure, I check the most recent `last_update` and its `refreshing` value. If `refreshing` is true, then don't try to refresh the materialized view.

```
EXECUTE 'SELECT 
           extract(epoch FROM now() - (last_update))::integer, 
           refreshing
         FROM refresh_status
         ORDER BY last_update DESC
         LIMIT 1' INTO update_seconds_ago, refreshing;

IF(updated_seconds_ago > 60 AND refreshing = FALSE) THEN
  -- the refresh block above
END IF;
```

However, I'm not sure the refreshing flag is being updated synchronously (I mean, it really waits for the refresh to actually be complete)

Is this approach rational or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As mentioned in [this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/119744/postgres-refresh-materialized-view-locks), "`REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW CONCURRENTLY` takes an `EXCLUSIVE` lock" on the table. Following the crumb trail to [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/explicit-locking.html) we can read that an `EXCLUSIVE` lock on a table "allows only concurrent `ACCESS SHARE` locks, i.e., only reads from the table can proceed". In the same paragraph we can see that "`EXCLUSIVE` conflicts with ... `EXCLUSIVE`", meaning that another `REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW CONCURRENTLY` statement, which requests the same `EXCLUSIVE` lock, will have to wait until the earlier `EXCLUSIVE` lock is released.

If you want to avoid waiting for this lock for an undefined period, you may want to set the [session variable `lock_timeout`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-LOCK-TIMEOUT) to a sensible value.

Comment: PS: do you think it makes any sense to keep this auxiliar table to tell concurrent (no pun intended) attempts that the MAT VIEW is busy and therefore should be left alone even if it seems it needs a refresh?

Comment: It's a matter of opinion; if you think it helps you can of course keep your logic. Note, however, that your function is subject to race conditions and therefore is not 100% reliable.

Comment: Do you think it's viable to check on pg_locks then to see if there's one referencing the mat view?

Comment: Again, race condition possible: there's a chance that a lock will be placed between you check `pg_locks` and start your refresh. A proper way to address lock conflicts is to set timeout and handle the error.

Comment: any changes to this in postgres 14.5?

Answer (score 5):

As noted by [mustaccio](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/23721/mustaccio), this question overlaps significantly with [Postgres Refresh Materialized View Locks](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/119744/postgres-refresh-materialized-view-locks).

However, while the [accepted answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/119788/116653) to that question has a link that answers this one, the answer to this question isn't directly included in that one.

So, to be specific: According to the [PostgreSQL manual page on explicit locking](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/explicit-locking.html) (Link is to the current version page, for PostGres 10), `REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW CONCURRENTLY` takes a `EXCLUSIVE` lock. The `EXCLUSIVE` lock appears to block all other locks *except* `ACCESS SHARE` - that includes other `EXCLUSIVE` locks.

So a second `REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW CONCURRENTLY` request on the same view will wait for the lock obtained by the first one to be released.

Comment: Thank you. I still marked @mustaccio's answer as accepted since he edited his text to be more specific to my question.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the answers by [mustaccio](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/23721/mustaccio) and [RDFozz](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/116653/rdfozz), I finally understood that `REFRESH ... CONCURRENTLY` taking an exclusive lock is the reason for which [PostgreSQL documentation says](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/sql-refreshmaterializedview.html):

> Even with this option **only one REFRESH at a time may run against any**
>   **one materialized view**.

I was afraid that this meant any attempt to make a simultaneous refresh **would throw an error**, but in the light of their answers, there isn't any special error involved. It's just a matter of locks that will enqueue simultaneous attempts. So the documentation could instead be interpreted as:

> The lock acquired during this operation will prevent any operation other than reading from the MATERIALIZED VIEW. Further attempts to refresh the Materialized View while a REFRESH ... CONCURRENTLY is running will queue up until the first lock is released.